# How to display sum of each column in react

Tags: reactjs, json

I want to display sum of pharmacy and sum of client number for each region in the table.

In each array object I have pharmacy and client data. I want to group them as per the region and
Region should be the column header.

I grouped the json object based on the region.

I not able to sum the data in the table.

I am getting first value only in the each column not the sum of table.

allstates.json:

```
 [
          {
            "id": "AL",
            "val": "01",
            "bgcolor": "green",
            "pharmacy": 10,
            "client": 20,
            "region": "Northeast"
          },
          {
            "id": "AR",
            "val": "05",
            "bgcolor": "green",
            "pharmacy": 10,
            "client": 12,
            "region": "Northeast"
          },
          {
            "id": "DE",
            "val": "10",
            "bgcolor": "red",
            "pharmacy": 10,
            "client": 20,
            "region": "MidAtlantic"
          }, 
           {
            "id": "FL",
            "val": "12",
            "bgcolor": "red",
            "pharmacy": 10,
            "client": 20,
            "region": "MidAtlantic"
          },
          {
            "id": "GU",
            "val": "66",
            "bgcolor": "red",
            "pharmacy": 30,
            "client": 20,
            "region": "Southease"
          },
          {
            "id": "HI",
            "val": "15",
            "bgcolor": "red",
            "pharmacy": 10,
            "client": 20,
            "region": "Southease"
          },
          {
            "id": "ID",
            "val": "16",
            "bgcolor": "red",
            "pharmacy": 10,
            "client": 20,
            "region": "Southease"
          },
          
]
```

summary.js:

```
import React from "react";
import allStates from "./data/allstates.json";
import groupBy from 'lodash/groupBy';
import './App.css'

const Summary = () => {

  let grouppedArray = groupBy(allStates, 'region')
  return (
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          {Object.keys(grouppedArray).map(key => {
            return (
              <th>{key}</th>
            )
          })}
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr>
          {Object.values(grouppedArray).map(values => {
            console.log(values, "values")
            var pharmacyTotal = 0;
            var clientTotal = 0;
            for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
              pharmacyTotal += values[i].pharmacy;
              console.log(values[i].pharmacy, "test")
              pharmacyTotal = values[i].pharmacy + i;
              clientTotal += values[i].client;
              return (
                <td>
                  <p>Pharmacy:{pharmacyTotal}</p>
                  <p>Client: {clientTotal}</p>
                </td>
              )

            }

          })}

        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );

};

export default Summary;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're returning in a for loop which will cause the loop to stop execution and exit the function. In your case, it's returning the first iteration of the loop and moving on. You also have a bug where you're resetting `pharmacyTotal` in the loop.

Instead, return outside of the loop like so:

```
{Object.values(grouppedArray).map((values) => {
  var pharmacyTotal = 0;
  var clientTotal = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    pharmacyTotal += values[i].pharmacy;
    clientTotal += values[i].client;
  }

  return (
    <td>
      <p>Pharmacy: {pharmacyTotal}</p>
      <p>Client: {clientTotal}</p>
    </td>
  );
})}
```

It looks like you're using lodash which provides a method called [sumBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#sumBy) which will simplify this code.

```
{Object.entries(grouppedArray).map(([key, values]) => (
  <td key={key}>
    <p>Pharmacy: {sumBy(values, "pharmacy")}</p>
    <p>Client: {sumBy(values, "client")}</p>
  </td>
))}
```

If you prefer to write the `sumBy` function yourself, have a look at [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

```
function sumBy(values, key) {
  return values.reduce((total, value) => total += value[key], 0)
}
```

Here's the code in action: https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-joliot-qy6qq

Answer (score 1):

First transform the data and sum up the costs per region

```js
const result = [{
    "id": "AL",
    "val": "01",
    "bgcolor": "green",
    "pharmacy": 10,
    "client": 20,
    "region": "Northeast"
  },
  {
    "id": "AR",
    "val": "05",
    "bgcolor": "green",
    "pharmacy": 10,
    "client": 12,
    "region": "Northeast"
  },
  {
    "id": "DE",
    "val": "10",
    "bgcolor": "red",
    "pharmacy": 10,
    "client": 20,
    "region": "MidAtlantic"
  },
  {
    "id": "FL",
    "val": "12",
    "bgcolor": "red",
    "pharmacy": 10,
    "client": 20,
    "region": "MidAtlantic"
  },
  {
    "id": "GU",
    "val": "66",
    "bgcolor": "red",
    "pharmacy": 30,
    "client": 20,
    "region": "Southease"
  },
  {
    "id": "HI",
    "val": "15",
    "bgcolor": "red",
    "pharmacy": 10,
    "client": 20,
    "region": "Southease"
  },
  {
    "id": "ID",
    "val": "16",
    "bgcolor": "red",
    "pharmacy": 10,
    "client": 20,
    "region": "Southease"
  },

].reduce((acc, current) => {
  const {
    pharmacy,
    client,
    region
  } = current;
  const currentRegionState = acc[region] ?? {
    pharmacyTotal: 0,
    clientTotal: 0
  };
  acc[region] = {
    clientTotal: currentRegionState.clientTotal + client,
    pharmacyTotal: currentRegionState.pharmacyTotal + pharmacy,
  };
  return acc;
}, {});


console.log(result);
```

And then you can iterate over that new data with Object.values

Answer (score 0):

you can use these `function` to group your data and then map through it to fill your table:

```
const groupData = (x)=>{
   let temp = [];
   let grouped = [];
   x.map(e=>{
     if(temp.includes(e.region)){
       let idx = grouped.findIndex(item=>item.region===e.region);
       grouped[idx].pharmacy += e.pharmacy;
       grouped[idx].client += e.client;
       return;
   } else {
      temp.push(e.region);
      grouped.push(e);
   }
   });
   return grouped;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the `result` from following to print accordingly in table.

```js
const grouppedArray = _(allStates).groupBy('region')
const result = grouppedArray.map((state) => ({
    region: state[0].region,
    client: _.sumBy(state, 'client'),
    pharamcy: _.sumBy(state, 'pharmacy')
  }))
```